# Order of services using systemd and legacy init.d services

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd, init.d, lsb

On my Fedora 23 system a database is started by systemd. Another service (hive-metastore) that depends on that database ist started through a init.d script. I'am unclear about what would be the correct way to make those services start in the right order (database before hive-megastore).

Comment: Get rid of the ancient init script and start it with a systemd unit.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that the best solution is simply to write a systemd unit for the hive-metastore service - so long as it has the same name systemd will use it in preference to the init script and it will likely be a lot easier to read and a lot more reliable.

You can control the ordering without that though, by adding `Before=hive-metastore.service` to the database service unit. That's best done using a dropin fragment, so create something like `/etc/systemd/system/database-name.service.d/hive-metastore.conf` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Before=hive-metastore.service
```

It's not quite what you would do if both were native systemd units, as in that case you would likely add the configuration to the other service, and use both `After` to control the ordering and `Requires` to ensure the database is started, but the ordering alone is sufficient if both services are enabled and ordering can be controlled from either end of the dependency.